# Trouble Converting code due to dual parentheses

Tags: c#, vb.net, legacy-code

I am trying to convert some old legacy from VB to C# but I am running into an issue with a particular area regarding dual parentheses

```
Dim _atts As List(Of String()) = List(Of String())
Dim tmp() As String = Me._atts.Item(AttNo)(ValNo).Split(_SVM)
```

I don't understand how I would write the (attNo)(valNo) in C#

I have tried the following but with no luck

```
List<string[]> _atts = new List<string[]>();
string[] tmp = this._atts[attNo](valNo).Split(_SVM);
```

Can someone enlighten me as to what the dual parenthesis actually do in VB?

Thanks

Comment: I dont remember VB at all but maybe its a 2d/jagged array syntax?  Like `someArray[1][2]`

Comment: Depends on what `_atts.Item` is..., more than likely a 2d array as @maccettura mentioned. Try `string[] tmp = this._atts[attNo][valNo].Split(_SVM);`

Comment: ahh no way, it was staring me in the face, never had experience with 2d/jagged arrays

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: @CorbinTaylor good luck and you are welcome!

Comment: I don't think that's VB6 code at all, maybe .Net.

Comment: It is the vb.net way to refer to an `item(row_index)(column_index)` inside a list

Comment: This is vb.Net, not vb6 for sure. As the first comment and current answer states - parenthesis in this context is used so indicate an indexer - so when translating to c# you convert them to square brackets - `string[] tmp = this._atts[attNo][valNo].Split(_SVM);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VB.Net the parenthesis in this context is used to access and iterate the values of an array (access the indexer). So if you have the member variable "exampleArray" with the values {"I", "Like", "Coding"}, it can be accessed like:

VB

```
Dim tmpStr as String = Me.exampleArray(1);
```

C#

```
string tmpStr = this.exampleArray[1];
```

now tmpStr contains the value "Like"

Now consider that you have an array "outerArray" that contains {exampleArray, someOtherArray}. If you want to get to the value "Like" you will need to index both arrays:

VB

```
Dim tmpStr as String = outerArray(0)(1)
```

C#

```
string tmpStr = outerArray[0][1];
```

The first set of square brackets (c#) or parenthesis (VB) is used to index "outerArray" to get access to "exampleArray".
Then the second set of square brackets or parenthesis is used to access the value "Like" within "exampleArray".

Ref: [Micorsoft Programming Guide - Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#iterating-through-an-array)

Comment: Plus one. Good answer. One wrinkle: It seems from the OP's question that in this case, the "outer" part is a `List(Of T)` rather than an array. But I think your C# code is also correct for a `List(Of T)` containing arrays.

Comment: Good answer thanks

Comment: @MarkJ you are correct, however, than bit of context was added to the question after I answered. Good catch though.

Comment: @AndrewMorton you are absolutely right. Changed it